# odbc_execute, odbc_fetch_row and odbc_result at the same time

Tags: php, odbc, hana

I have a prepared statement built inside a class:

```
function reader($ser)
    {
        $pstmt=odbc_prepare($this->conn,'SELECT TOP 1 "name"
        FROM '.$this->table.' WHERE 
        "surname" LIKE ? ');        
        return odbc_execute($pstmt,array("$ser"));  
    }
```

And gets its $ser through a post

```
$serTab=$product->reader($ser);
```

Example $ser :

```
$ser=' \'3221252\'';
```

When it comes to displaying values these functions return nothing (but they are working with odbc_exec):

```
while(odbc_fetch_row($serTab)) 
 { 
 for($i=1;$i<=odbc_num_fields($serTab);$i++) 
 {
echo odbc_result($serTab,$i);                       
 }
 }
```

Are there any alternatives for these functions?  Why it doesn't return anything with obdc_execute?How do I fix this?

Can't use PDO because of this error:

> Conversion of parameter/column (5) from data type NVARCHAR to ASCII
> failed

I have no authorization to make changes on database, hence on data types.DBMS: SAP Hana

Comment: Is there supposed to be a space in `$ser=' \'3221252\'';` after the opening `'`?  Also your solution below is just removing the quotes, which is what was suggested in the other answer which you say doesn't work.  Finally, do you need `like` if you are looking for a specific value?

Comment: When I removed the space, odbc_prepare evaluated $ser as file. And I don't know, it didn't work when I removed the quotes by hand. I needed LIKE for future work. @NigelRen

Comment: Now I see,I changed "$ser" to $ser too @NigelRen

Comment: Just having a look at the odbc stuff, can you remove the `"` round the various column names as this looks incorrect (i.e. name and surname).  I'm also confused about how you are matching surname against '3221252'?!

Comment: Removing " s doesn't work for hana and yes 3221252 is something like id for now... @NigelRen

Comment: Looking at https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/saphana-odbc-php-linux.rst, the example has `$query = odbc_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM Buckets WHERE Name = ?");` which doesn't have quotes round the name.

Comment: It says invalid column name, probably becasue I used ' instead of " outside. I will try that too. @NigelRen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed it by adding

```
$ser=str_replace(array("'", "\'"," "),"",$ser)
```

before

```
odbc_prepare
```

and changed

```
 return odbc_execute($pstmt,array("$ser"));
```

to

```
 return odbc_execute($pstmt,array($ser));
```

Answer (score 1):

[`odbc_execute`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-execute.php) just returns a boolean to indicate
success or failure. What you need to return is `$pstmt`:

```
function reader($ser)
{
    $pstmt = odbc_prepare($this->conn, 'SELECT TOP 1 "name"
        FROM '.$this->table.' WHERE 
        "surname" LIKE ? ');        
    if(!odbc_execute($pstmt, array("$ser")))
        die('odbc_execute failed');
    return $pstmt;
}
```

Comment: still returns nothing unfortunately

Comment: @wittream Your query probably returns no rows.

Comment: no, it returns when I type \'3221252\' instead of ? with odbc_exec. I thought it is about quotation marks of "$ser" or ? or maybe \'3221252\' while using odbc_execute.Tried a different combinations but still no solution.

Comment: @wittream Try removing the quotes: `$ser = '3221252';`

Comment: invalid column name 3221252